# Loading data from fixtures to the database ( associations )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, yaml, fixtures

I have two models, Project and Todo.

Project stores an array of Todos.

Migration for Project:

```
  def up
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

Migration for Todo:

```
  def up
    create_table :todos do |t|
      t.string :text, null: false
      t.boolean :isCompleted, null:false
      t.integer :project_id, null:false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end
```

todo.rb

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

projects.yml

```
family:
  title: 'Семья'

work:
  title: 'Работа'

therest:
  title: 'Прочее'
```

todos.yml

```
family_todos:
  text: 'Купить молоко'
  isCompleted: false
  project_id: family

work_todos:
  text: 'Закончить проект'
  isCompleted: false
  project_id: work

therest_todos:
  text: 'Познать бесконечность'
  isCompleted: true
  project_id: therest
```

How can I connect them properly, so when I call a project I can see all the todos inside it? Plus I'm curious how can I add the date via the yml files like an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the better way to link the association between tables is by using references. You can do this to your todos table

```
def up
 create_table :todos do |t|
  t.string :text, null: false
  t.boolean :isCompleted, null:false
  t.references :project, references: :projects, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps null: false
 end
end
```

This will create a field called project_id in your todos table. Hence you have a project table with has_many todos.

There are different ways you can preload database. You can use seeds.rb file where you can write your code to read from yml file and load to database.
You can do something like this

```
proj = Project.create(title: family)
```

If you have an array of all the family todos, then you can put it in database like this

```
##Family todos
loop through
  proj.todos << Todo.create(...fields...)
end
```

Comment: Can you answer me - I how I can get all the todos?
For example I need to print all the todos from my family project.

<%= project.todos . . .%>

Comment: You can do <%= Project.where(title: "family").todos %>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pre-fill your database, then better way is to use `seeds.rb`, which is located in `db/`.

Simply use ruby here and classes from your rails application, e.g., create a project and a todo for it:

```
project = Project.create!(...)
project.todos.create!(...)
```

And then simply run `rake db:seed` to execute it.

You can read more with examples here: http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html